# Directx11 Linker Error

Tags: c++, directx-11

```
            // include the basic windows header file
            #include <windows.h>
            #include <windowsx.h>
            #include <d3d11.h>
            #include <d3dx11.h>
            #include <d3dx10.h>

            // include the Direct3D Library file
            #pragma comment (lib, "d3d11.lib")
            #pragma comment (lib, "d3dx11.lib")
            #pragma comment (lib, "d3dx10.lib")

            // global declarations
            IDXGISwapChain *swapchain;             // the pointer to the swap chain interface
            ID3D11Device *dev;                     // the pointer to our Direct3D device interface
            ID3D11DeviceContext *devcon;           // the pointer to our Direct3D device context

            // function prototypes
            void InitD3D(HWND hWnd);     // sets up and initializes Direct3D
            void CleanD3D(void);         // closes Direct3D and releases memory



            HRESULT D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(
                IDXGIAdapter *pAdapter,
                D3D_DRIVER_TYPE DriverType,
                HMODULE Software,
                UINT Flags,
                D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL *pFeatureLevels,
                UINT FeatureLevels,
                UINT SDKVersion,
                DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC *pSwapChainDesc,
                IDXGISwapChain **ppSwapChain,
                ID3D11Device **ppDevice,
                D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL *pFeatureLevel,
                ID3D11DeviceContext **ppDeviceContext);



            // the WindowProc function prototype
            LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd,
                                     UINT message,
                                     WPARAM wParam,
                                     LPARAM lParam);



            // the entry point for any Windows program
            int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                               HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                               LPSTR lpCmdLine,
                               int nCmdShow)
            {
                // the handle for the window, filled by a function
                HWND hWnd;
                // this struct holds information for the window class
                WNDCLASSEX wc;

                // clear out the window class for use
                ZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));

                // fill in the struct with the needed information
                wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
                wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
                wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
                wc.hInstance = hInstance;
                wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
                wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
                wc.lpszClassName = L"WindowClass1";

                // register the window class
                RegisterClassEx(&wc);

                RECT wr = {0, 0, 500, 400};    // set the size, but not the position
                AdjustWindowRect(&wr, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, FALSE);    // adjust the size

                // create the window and use the result as the handle
                hWnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL,
                                      L"WindowClass1",    // name of the window class
                                      L"Our First Windowed Program",   // title of the window
                                      WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,    // window style
                                      300,    // x-position of the window
                                      300,    // y-position of the window
                                      500,    // width of the window
                                      400,    // height of the window
                                      NULL,    // we have no parent window, NULL
                                      NULL,    // we aren't using menus, NULL
                                      hInstance,    // application handle
                                      NULL);    // used with multiple windows, NULL

                // display the window on the screen
                ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);

                // enter the main loop:
                // enter the main loop:

                // this struct holds Windows event messages
                MSG msg = {0};

                // Enter the infinite message loop
                while(TRUE)
                {
                    // Check to see if any messages are waiting in the queue
                    if(PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
                    {
                        // translate keystroke messages into the right format
                        TranslateMessage(&msg);

                        // send the message to the WindowProc function
                        DispatchMessage(&msg);

                        // check to see if it's time to quit
                        if(msg.message == WM_QUIT)
                            break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Run game code here
                        // ...
                        // ...
                    }
                }

                // return this part of the WM_QUIT message to Windows
                return msg.wParam;
            }

            // this is the main message handler for the program
            LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
            {
                // sort through and find what code to run for the message given
                switch(message)
                {
                    // this message is read when the window is closed
                    case WM_DESTROY:
                        {
                            // close the application entirely
                            PostQuitMessage(0);
                            return 0;
                        } break;
                }

                // Handle any messages the switch statement didn't
                return DefWindowProc (hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
            }

            // this function initializes and prepares Direct3D for use
            void InitD3D(HWND hWnd)
            {
                // create a struct to hold information about the swap chain
                DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC scd;

                // clear out the struct for use
                ZeroMemory(&scd, sizeof(DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC));

                // fill the swap chain description struct
                scd.BufferCount = 1;                                    // one back buffer
                scd.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;     // use 32-bit color
                scd.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;      // how swap chain is to be used
                scd.OutputWindow = hWnd;                                // the window to be used
                scd.SampleDesc.Count = 4;                               // how many multisamples
                scd.Windowed = TRUE;                                    // windowed/full-screen mode

                // create a device, device context and swap chain using the information in the scd struct
                D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(NULL,
                                              D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
                                              NULL,
                                              NULL,
                                              NULL,
                                              NULL,
                                              D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
                                              &scd,
                                              &swapchain,
                                              &dev,
                                              NULL,
                                              &devcon);
            }

            // this is the function that cleans up Direct3D and COM
            void CleanD3D()
            {
                // close and release all existing COM objects
                swapchain->Release();
                dev->Release();
                devcon->Release();
            }

            Error   29  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "long __cdecl D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(struct IDXGIAdapter *,enum D3D_DRIVER_TYPE,struct HINSTANCE__ *,unsigned int,enum D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL *,unsigned int,unsigned int,struct DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC *,struct IDXGISwapChain * *,struct ID3D11Device * *,enum D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL *,struct ID3D11DeviceContext * *)" (?D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain@@YAJPAUIDXGIAdapter@@W4D3D_DRIVER_TYPE@@PAUHINSTANCE__@@IPAW4D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL@@IIPAUDXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC@@PAPAUIDXGISwapChain@@PAPAUID3D11Device@@3PAPAUID3D11DeviceContext@@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl InitD3D(struct HWND__ *)" (?InitD3D@@YAXPAUHWND__@@@Z)   C:\Users\Eric\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\d3dinit\d3dinit\Source.obj  d3dinit
```

My lib directory is specified as:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Lib\x64

As well my linker settings specify these libs:

d3d11.lib
d3dx11.lib
d3dx10.lib

The linker error I pasted at the end of the code block.
I am wondering what may be the cause of the linker error?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: By any chance, are you compiling under VS a debug configuration of your project ?

Comment: Yes actually. I had a bit of trouble figuring out which libraries to use x86 or x64. Even though I have a x64 processor the programs seem to work best with x86 libraries I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain forward declaration is wrong. Pointers to pFeatureLevels and pSwapChainDesc should be const. This means that linker searches for a bit different D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain function and can't find it. Simpliest way to fix it is just to remove D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain forward declaration.

BTW there is no point in including dx10 headers and linking dx10 libraries, when you use dx11. Additionally DXSDK is deprecated and replaced by [Windows8 SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).